# Scala Spark Pairwise Differences by Group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a data set like the following:

```
phone   callStartTimestamp        rank
p1      2020-03-24 18:10:15.1015  1
p1      2020-03-24 18:13:11.1311  2
p1      2020-03-26 14:40:50.4050  3
p1      2020-10-26 15:58:23.5823  4

p2      2020-09-03 23:44:21.4421  1
p2      2020-05-07 05:36:00.3600  2
p2      2020-04-11 13:48:11.4811  3
```

How do you calculate the differences in timestamp for every row of a phone number? I'm only interested in differences >= 0.

For example, for p1, the calculations I want would be and only be:

```
(2020-10-26 15:58:23.5823) - (2020-03-24 18:13:11.1311)
(2020-10-26 15:58:23.5823) - (2020-03-24 18:10:15.1015)
(2020-10-26 15:58:23.5823) - (2020-03-26 14:40:50.4050)
(2020-03-26 14:40:50.4050) - (2020-03-24 18:13:11.1311)
(2020-03-26 14:40:50.4050) - (2020-03-24 18:10:15.1015)
(2020-03-24 18:13:11.1311) - (2020-03-24 18:10:15.1015)

For p2, the calculations I want would be:
(2020-09-03 23:44:21.4421) - (2020-05-07 05:36:00.3600)
(2020-09-03 23:44:21.4421) - (2020-04-11 13:48:11.4811)
(2020-05-07 05:36:00.3600) - (2020-04-11 13:48:11.4811)
```

The pseudo code that would look something like (it doesn't do everything I am looking for):

```
dfd.withColumn("time_gap",
            to_timestamp(col("callStartTimestamp2")).cast("Long") - 
            to_timestamp(col("callStartTimestamp")).cast("Long")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a self join on the required conditions:

```
val df2 = df.join(
    df.toDF("phone2","callStartTimestamp2","rank2"),
    expr("(phone = phone2) and (callStartTimestamp < callStartTimestamp2)")
).drop(
    "phone2", "rank2"
).withColumn(
    "time_gap",
    $"callStartTimestamp2".cast("long") - $"callStartTimestamp".cast("long")
)

df2.show(false)
+-----+------------------------+----+------------------------+--------+
|phone|callStartTimestamp      |rank|callStartTimestamp2     |time_gap|
+-----+------------------------+----+------------------------+--------+
|p1   |2020-03-24 18:10:15.1015|1   |2020-10-26 15:58:23.5823|18654488|
|p1   |2020-03-24 18:10:15.1015|1   |2020-03-26 14:40:50.405 |160235  |
|p1   |2020-03-24 18:10:15.1015|1   |2020-03-24 18:13:11.1311|176     |
|p1   |2020-03-24 18:13:11.1311|2   |2020-10-26 15:58:23.5823|18654312|
|p1   |2020-03-24 18:13:11.1311|2   |2020-03-26 14:40:50.405 |160059  |
|p1   |2020-03-26 14:40:50.405 |3   |2020-10-26 15:58:23.5823|18494253|
|p2   |2020-05-07 05:36:00.36  |2   |2020-09-03 23:44:21.4421|10346901|
|p2   |2020-04-11 13:48:11.4811|3   |2020-05-07 05:36:00.36  |2216869 |
|p2   |2020-04-11 13:48:11.4811|3   |2020-09-03 23:44:21.4421|12563770|
+-----+------------------------+----+------------------------+--------+
```